# How to get Bootstrap-4 working with php & html?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I downloaded Bootstrap 4 to replace on a certain site with Bootstrap 3 and can't seem to get it working. It worked fine with 3.

```
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/school/courses.php">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/cubing/cubing.php">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/cubing/cubing.php">Cubing</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">-Attacks</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cubify</a></li>
        </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: visit this link for more information https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to add comments yet (not enough reputation), so I'll do it here.

Aside from the fact if the Bootstrap classes might have changed... Like @Rob said, your markup is wrong.
Seeing how you are a beginner in HTML, start with this site here. It explains the very basic setup of a HTML page. 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Your **head** tag is missing for example. It doesn't start `<head>`, or end `</head>`. Which is the section where the **meta** and **link** tags are supposed to be.
The `<header>` tag you used, should go into the **body** tag.

Just as a test, does this work? Assuming that this what you posted was an exact copy of your site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/school/courses.php">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/cubing/cubing.php">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/cubing/cubing.php">Cubing</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">-Attacks</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cubify</a></li>
        </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```